# Powershell Reading inner Folder

Tags: powershell

I put together a Robocopy script to backup data, but the problem I am having is the script is reading the parent folder and trying to execute the robocopy filters and error out.
what I would like for it to do is indent one and start copying the subfolder and use the filter there. the file structure is

Users\tim jones, sam adams

I just want the tim jones folder and the sam adams user folders with the Robocopy filter added to it. any help is welcomed

```
$Comp = Read-Host 'Please enter a computer name or IP'

do{
If (Test-Connection $Comp -quiet -Count 1) {
Write-host 'The host responded' -ForegroundColor "yellow"
Read-Host 'Press any key to continue...' | Out-Null
$ping = "ture"
Clear-Host

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp -class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Select- Object Name,@{label='LastLogon';expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon)}}

New-Item -Path \\skyzone\t$\sky\ -ItemType directory 

$SourcePath = "\\$Comp\C$\Users\";

$TargetPath = "\\skyzone\t$\sky"; 

#Users libraries  
$PicturesLibrary = ("\Pictures"); 
$Downloads = ("\Downloads"); 
$Favorites = ("\Favorites");
$Documents = ("\Documents");
$Desktop = ("\Desktop");
$Video = ("\Videos");

#User Outlook files and logs 
$Outlook = ("\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook") 

$argsFromFolders = ("$SourcePath\$PicturesLibrary","$SourcePath\$Downloads","$SourcePath\$Favorites","$SourcePath\$Documents","$SourcePath\$Desktop","$SourcePath\$Video" ,"$SourcePath\$Outlook"); 
$argsToFolders = ("$TargetPath\Pictures","$TargetPath\Downloads","$TargetPath\Favorites","$TargetPath\Documents","$TargetPath\Desktop","$TargetPath\Videos","$TargetPath\Outlook"); 


For ($i=0; $i -lt $argsFromFolders.Length; $i++) { 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Processing" $argsFromFolders[$i] "To" $argsToFolders[$i]; 


robocopy $argsFromFolders[$i] $argsToFolders[$i] *.*  /MT:16 /XJ *.pst /R:3 /W:1 /NP /e /xf *.vmdk *.vmem *.iso *.exe *.ost desktop.ini /tee /Log+:

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and the sample is incomplete. You refer to `$user` which is never created and there are no `robocopy`-calls here. Because of this I can't give you a complete solution.

Take a look at this example source-path in your code:

```
$SourcePath = "\\localhost\C$\Users\";
$PicturesLibrary = ("\Pictures"); 
"$SourcePath\$PicturesLibrary"

#Output
\\localhost\C$\Users\\\Pictures
```

1. There are too many backslashes in the spot where you joined the two strings. Remove them from the variables or use `Join-Path`

   ```
   $SourcePath = "\\localhost\C$\Users\"
   $PicturesLibrary = "\Pictures" 
   Join-Path $SourcePath $PicturesLibrary

   #Output
   \\localhost\C$\Users\Pictures
   ```

   Or

   ```
   $SourcePath = "\\localhost\C$\Users"
   $PicturesLibrary = "Pictures"
   "$SourcePath\$PicturesLibrary"

   #Output
   \\localhost\C$\Users\Pictures
   ```
2. The username is missing. You need to use `Get-Childitem` on the `$sourcePath` to get the list of users in the first place and loop through those.

   Sample:

   ```
   $SourcePath = "\\localhost\C$\Users\"
   Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath |
   #Get folders only... And exlude public?
   Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -ne 'Public' } |
   ForEach-Object {
       #Code to run for each user-folder
       $PicturesLibrary = ("Pictures")
       Join-Path $_.FullName $PicturesLibrary
   }
   \\localhost\C$\Users\Default.migrated\Pictures
   \\localhost\C$\Users\defaultuser0\Pictures
   \\localhost\C$\Users\frode\Pictures
   ```

Update: Try something like this (untested).

```
$Comp = Read-Host 'Please enter a computer name or IP'

If (Test-Connection $Comp -quiet -Count 1) {

    Write-host 'The host responded' -ForegroundColor "yellow"
    Read-Host 'Press any key to continue...' | Out-Null
    Clear-Host

    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp -class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Select- Object Name,@{label='LastLogon';expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastLogon)}}

    $TargetPath = '\\skyzone\t$\sky'
    if(-not (Test-Path -Path $TargetPath -PathType Container)) { New-Item -Path $TargetPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null }

    $Folderlist = ("Pictures","Downloads","Favorites","Documents","Desktop","Videos","Outlook"); 

    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Comp\C$\Users\" |
    #Get folders only... And exclude public?
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -ne 'Public' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $user = $_.Name

        foreach ($folder in $Folderlist) {
            $from = Join-Path $_.FullName $folder
            $to = Join-Path $TargetPath "$user\$folder"

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Processing '$from' To '$to'"
            robocopy $from $to *.*  /MT:16 /XJ *.pst /R:3 /W:1 /NP /e /xf *.vmdk *.vmem *.iso *.exe *.ost desktop.ini /tee /Log+:\\apgrwkate1090f\t$\dren\$user\backup.txt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was having trouble getting the complete code to post, so I only put up half the code. let me try again

Comment: I added the reset of the code. example 2  is along the line of what I am trying to get done at this point. I would like the script to loop through all the users in the "users folder" while applying the robocopy filter and place the result on the server

Comment: The sample is still incomplete. `$user` and `$outlook` is still not defined and your scriptblocks aren't closed. This question is now also too broad. See update. That's the last update from me as this question should have been closed.

Comment: $user and $outlook was from when I was testing enter individual user, and has been removed.

Comment: $user and $outlook was from when I was testing enter individual user, and has been removed. I am still new to PowerShell, with that said I don't understand what you mean by its now also too board? the locations of the files will remain the same the only changing var is the computer name. if I am missing something please same so,

Comment: If you only want those two users no matter which computer it is then replace the get-childitem loop with a loop through those two values and change the from and to paths. By too broad I mean that there are too many things to change to make your sample work the way you wanted. If you need to edit the question multiple times to make it work, then the question was too unclear to begin with.

Comment: Constructive criticism is always good. the problem i ran into now is the hidden outlook pst. that is location at "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook" how would I retrieve those?

Comment: Change `Outlook` in the array in my sample to `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`. If you don't want that path in the target-location, add a simple if test to fix the to-path when the foreach-loop is processing that specific from-value. Or you could use a hashtable to store from-path (key) and to-path (value).